# Jsoup - extracting text

Tags: java, iteration, jsoup, text-extraction

I need to extract text from a node like this:

```
<div>
    Some text <b>with tags</b> might go here.
    <p>Also there are paragraphs</p>
    More text can go without paragraphs<br/>
</div>
```

And I need to build:

```
Some text <b>with tags</b> might go here.
Also there are paragraphs
More text can go without paragraphs
```

`Element.text` returns just all content of the div. `Element.ownText` - everything that is not inside children elements. Both are wrong. Iterating through `children` ignores text nodes.

Is there are way to iterate contents of an element to receive text nodes as well. E.g.

- Text node - Some text
- Node <b>  - with tags
- Text node - might go here.
- Node <p>  - Also there are paragraphs
- Text node -  More text can go without paragraphs
- Node <br> - <empty>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Element.children()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#children%28%29) returns an [Elements](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Elements.html) object - a list of [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) objects.  Looking at the parent class, [Node](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html), you'll see methods to give you access to arbitrary nodes, not just Elements, such as [Node.childNodes()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes%28%29).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "<div>" +
            "    Some text <b>with tags</b> might go here." +
            "    <p>Also there are paragraphs</p>" +
            "    More text can go without paragraphs<br/>" +
            "</div>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
    Element div = doc.select("div").first();
    int i = 0;

    for (Node node : div.childNodes()) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %s",
                i,
                node.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                node.toString()));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1 TextNode 
 Some text 
2 Element <b>with tags</b>
3 TextNode  might go here. 
4 Element <p>Also there are paragraphs</p>
5 TextNode  More text can go without paragraphs
6 Element <br/>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (Element el : doc.select("body").select("*")) {

        for (TextNode node : el.textNodes()) {

                    node.text() ));

        }

    }
```

Comment: I guess you are missing a system.out.println there in the loop, but this is the example that works fine for extracting all text nodes recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want text only (no tags) my solution is below.
Output is:
Some text with tags might go here. Also there are paragraphs. More text can go without paragraphs

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = 
                "<div>"  
            +   "    Some text <b>with tags</b> might go here."
            +   "    <p>Also there are paragraphs.</p>"
            +   "    More text can go without paragraphs<br/>" 
            +   "</div>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
    Element div = doc.select("div").first();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    stripTags(builder, div.childNodes());
    System.out.println("Text without tags: " + builder.toString());
}

/**
 * Strip tags from a List of type <code>Node</code>
 * @param builder StringBuilder : input and output
 * @param nodesList List of type <code>Node</code>
 */
public static void stripTags (StringBuilder builder, List<Node> nodesList) {

    for (Node node : nodesList) {
        String nodeName  = node.nodeName();

        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase("#text")) {
            builder.append(node.toString());
        } else {
            // recurse
            stripTags(builder, node.childNodes());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use TextNode for this purpose:

```
List<TextNode> bodyTextNode = doc.getElementById("content").textNodes();
    String html = "";
    for(TextNode txNode:bodyTextNode){
        html+=txNode.text();
    }
```