# Extracting text from any web page with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to extract the text from web page http://www.zomato.com/mumbai/starbucks-coffee-fort including any newlines, spaces in the original. For that I have written following piece of code with the help of answer at [Jsoup - extracting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177867/jsoup-extracting-text) :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zomato.com/mumbai/starbucks-coffee-fort").get();
Elements div = doc.select("div");
for (Element d : div) {
  for (Node nd : d.childNodes()) {
    System.out.println(nd.toString());
  }
}
```

But it's not working as expected. Actually it should print text of  as well as text
of all its child nodes. Also I want this code a bit generalized so that it can
extract text from any web page. Please help.

Comment: please provide some of your code.

Comment: Actually the code written above is all that i have written. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is generalized tool for scraping text from any web page ;)

Solution for this case:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zomato.com/mumbai/starbucks-coffee-fort").get();
Elements div = doc.select("div.res-review-body > div > p");
for (Element paragraph : div) {
    System.out.println(paragraph.text());
}
```

Result:

```
Firstly I would say it was tough to even start writing a review for a brand like 'Starbucks'.
(...)
```