# Using jSoup, how can I extract text that isn't surrounded by any type of tags?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have this HTML code here:

```
<hr />
<h3>Academic Recovery and Probation Conference Journal</h3>The Recovery Progress Journal is used to
record and guide conference discussions and to monitor students’ academic, behavioral and social
progress. 
<br />
```

As you can see, the text under the 'h3' header doesn't have any tags surrounding it? I am using jSoup to put this info into an Android app. How would I extract just that paragraph of text if it doesn't have tags defining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using Jsoup by itself without any other parsing. Jsoup locates elements in the DOM and then allows you to get access to the data of the elements.

You're going to have to find the smallest element that encloses the paragraph that you want, run .text() on it, and then parse the results of .text() yourself.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. I'll have to do it the long way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answered over here (thankfully):

> [Jsoup - extracting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177867/jsoup-extracting-text)

Paraphrased version for the lazy:

```
// You need to get Nodes, not Elements
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
Element div = doc.select("div").first();

for (Node node : div.childNodes()) {
    System.out.println(
        String.format(
            "%s %s",
            node.getClass().getSimpleName(),
            node.toString()
        )
    );
}
```